# How can I call a hexColor in Xcode5.0 iOS7.0

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I need to use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/256.0 green:53/256.0 blue:0/256.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

in my appDelegate.m, but I need to set the UIColor to hex # "669900"
How can I accomplish this in a simple manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a category to UIColor - UIColor (HexAdditions)

In UIColor+HexAdditions.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (HexAdditions)
+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hexString;
+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hexString alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;

@end
```

In UIColor+HexAdditions.m

```
#import "UIColor+HexAdditions.h"

@implementation UIColor (HexAdditions)

+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hexString{
    hexString = [[hexString lowercaseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    switch (hexString.length) {
        case 6:
            hexString = [hexString stringByAppendingString:@"ff"];
            break;
        case 8:
            //correct length
            break;
        default:
            return nil;
            break;
    }
    uint32_t rgba;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgba];
    return [self colorWithHexValue:rgba];
}

+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hexString alpha:(CGFloat)alpha{
    int alpha_ = alpha * 255;
    hexString = [hexString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%02x",alpha_];
    return [self colorWithHexString:hexString];
}

+ (UIColor*)colorWithHexValue:(uint32_t)rgba{
    CGFloat red = ((rgba & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat green = ((rgba & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat blue = ((rgba & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat alpha = (rgba & 0x000000FF) / 255.0f;
    return [self colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

And you can use it as

```
[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];
```

Comment: Very nice. So the written methods you provided do the hex color for me automatically?  This seems a bit complicated but I'm sure it works..

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a very fast response, and this class looks extremely useful. @johnykutty

Comment: Thank you. Happy coding. And remember thats not class. Its a category to UIColor :)

Comment: ahhh. That's the first time I've ever heard of a "category". Wait.. so do I not add this by adding an objective-c class file?

Comment: You can read about category from here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html and here http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories.html  and

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44197/discussion-between-johnykutty-and-whitehatprince)